# No response from service, node won't close either

Tags: ros, callback, ros-kinetic, service, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running into an issue with calling a service in the callback function of a listener. I couldn't find a way to call the service as the initialization of the client stood in the main, but moving that to the function as well gave a whole different series of errors, so i tried to implement a work-around

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "final/add_duplicates.h"
#include <string>
int message = 0;
std::string text;

void preparefortrouble(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
text = msg->data.c_str();
message = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "add_duplicates_client");
    ros::init(argc, argv, "print_twice");
    ros::NodeHandle n;  
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("print_twice", 1, preparefortrouble);
    ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<final::add_duplicates>("add_duplicates");
    
    while (1){
        while (message == 1)
        {
            final::add_duplicates srv;
            srv.request.text = text.c_str();
            srv.request.nrOfDuplicates = 2;
            if (client.call(srv) == false)
            {
                ROS_ERROR("Orga het is stuk");
            }
            message = 0;
        }
    }
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

The server has been tested and works fine, the topic is called in the terminal.
However, when i use this node, it cannot be close by crtl-c and sending a message to the topic results in nothing.

i try to call it with

```
$ rostopic pub /print_twice std_msgs/string “hello"
```

and my srv file is as following:

```
string text
int32 nrOfDuplicates
---
string multitext
```

thanks for the support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283677/no-response-from-service,-node-won%27t-close-either/) by [Pigskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33843/pigskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-25**:\

> I couldn't find a way to call the service as the initialization of the client stood in the main

I don't really understand what you write here, so I've ignored that for now.

What are you trying to do *really*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> and sending a message to the topic results in nothing

This is most likely caused by the fact that your node does not handle any incoming events (ie: msgs on topics).

To remedy that you'd need to either call `ros::spin()` or periodically call `ros::spinOnce()`.

Your node does the former, but only *after* it has progressed through the `while`-loops. And this is the problem, as in order to get through the loops, your node needs to handle incoming events (otherwise `message` will never be set to `1`). This seems to be a deadlock situation.

I would suggest to avoid the two nested `while`-loops, as I believe they are not needed and only complicate things.

What are you actually trying to do and what are the two `while`-loops supposed to achieve?

Some other things I noticed:

- there is no `ros::Rate::sleep()` in the body of either of your `while`-loops (busy-wait, 100% cpu usage)
- you have two calls to `ros::init(..)` in there, I'm not sure that is going to work (or at the very least: it's not needed)
- avoid using `final` for anything (unless you want to declare something as *final*). It is a C++11 keyword: [final specifier (since C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

> However, when i use this node, it cannot be close by crtl-c

if you need to run a `while`-loop, make sure to use something like `while (ros::ok()) { .. }`. This makes your node check whether it has been requested to exit.

See also [wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

---

Edit: (nested) `while`-loops are not necessarily a good idea with an event-based, asynchronous framework such as ROS. You may want to re-evaluate your approach and possibly restructure your node.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0